# Google Schema.org alternate to PriceSpecification

Tags: google-search, microdata, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm back with another Schema.org / Google inconsistency.

Our store sells many products that have different variants each with their own price. For example a heater may be sold in any of 8 BTU levels with a higher BTU heater costing more. We present all variants on the same product page and display a price range until the user selects their specific variant.

The question is **how can I tell Google that the product has a price range?** Or if I can enumerate the variants as individual sub-products with their own prices that may suffice.

What we've tried:

We started by using `Offer`'s `priceSpecification` property. We tried this with both an itemtype of `PriceSpecification` and of `UnitPriceSpecification`. These left us with the Error: *Incomplete microdata with schema.org.* in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool and even more importantly with error *Missing: price* in our Webmaster Tool's Structured Data tab (which nuked our rich snippet). This is supposedly because Google erroneously expects the `Offer`→`price` property to always be set even if `priceSpecification` is in use (see: [This SO post on `priceSpecification`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15006029/2992570) ). Example:

```html
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope itemprop="offers">
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification" itemscope itemprop="priceSpecification" class="price-box">
        <span id="product-price-6048" class="price">$571.20 - $894.75</span>
        <meta content="571.2" itemprop="minPrice">
        <meta content="894.75" itemprop="maxPrice">
        <meta content="USD" itemprop="priceCurrency">
    </div>
</div>
```

We also tried just passing the human-readable string "$571.20 - $897.75" as the `Offer`→`price` property. That obviously didn't work as Google didn't know how to parse it.

According to point 8 of [this SEOMoz article](http://moz.com/blog/the-lowdown-on-structured-data-and-schemaorg-your-questions-answered) you can use `AggregateOffer` as a workaround to list a price range for a product/product-set. However Schema.org clearly states [`AggregateOffer`](http://schema.org/AggregateOffer) is for

> When a single product is associated with multiple offers (for example, the same pair of shoes is offered by different merchants)

While it will likely work for now, using `AggregateOffer` in our case seems like a kludge that's liable to break.

So again, how can I inform Google that a product price is in a range depending on user selections? Has anyone had any success using the `PriceSpecification` for a product, especially to list a product price range? Or is there another way to accomplish the same result?

Comment: I see that your using `itemscope=""` is this because you copied from source using a browser? only reason I ask it should `itemscope` without the brackets.

Comment: I do not want to be critical of the schema.org specification especially since I am so grateful and supportive of the effort. But it is clearly frustrating and incomplete. It requires a lot of work and experimentation. I suspect that a re-work of the specification will become required at some point. You have my empathy. If I can help, I will chime in.

Comment: @bybe That's correct. Fixed now.

Comment: In my case I'm showing products that are available from multiple vendors, with different prices but for the same product. Just putting in multiple `itemprop="offers"` each with its own price results in Google displaying a range of prices on the result, saying e.g. "$27.00 - $35.00". The collection of offers is wrapped in a single `div` with `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month of testing different permutations of the SEOMoz AggregateOffer solution I've come to the conclusion it doesn't work.  Until Google supports the PriceSpecification property of the offer and stops requiring a single fixed price for offer there isn't a way to list a group of products/variants under one price-range umbrella.

If anyone finds a better solution post it here.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue at MammothWorkwear.com on products offered on a Bulk Buy http://mammothworkwear.com/honeywell-multisafe-parka-jacket-p2689.htm

Comment: @JohnDoherty - No I haven't, sorry. But admittedly I haven't looked at it since I posted this.  It's possible Google now supports the PriceSpec or some other markup.

Comment: I find that Google can sometimes be an unrelenting jerk about some things. They get so rigid and can demand whatever they want because they are so huge. I had product related problems with my father's website in sending e-commerce data to Google because there was a lot of custom items that didn't have brand info or other specifications that they want. This was years ago and I had to give up on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a different context. 
My solution was to set the price of the offer to the lowest price and then specify an instance of PriceSpecification where I state the minimum price that is of EQUAL value to the value in the price tag and then a maximum price. 
This effectively means that there is a product with price X AND that X price corresponds to the minimum price.

It's not perfect, but at least all the data is there. I've done this in JSON-LD as it is the recommendation from Google, see the example above to specify more that one offer to the same product and then for each offer specify a price and a minimum price. You could also specify the maximum price. That way it is clear that the offer is a range:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "description": "This Fancy Product is all you will ever need.",
  "name": "My Fancy Product",
  "model" :"https://www.freebase.com/m/02116f",
  "offers": [
        {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "category": "base",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
      "priceSpecification":{
        "minPrice": "10.00",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR"
      },
      "price": "10.00"
    },
    {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "category": "high-end",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceSpecification":{
        "minPrice": "50.00",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR"
      },
      "price": "50.00"
  }
    ]
    }
```